# Is it was or were?

Tags: verbs

Which one is here correct?
"...the employment rate of women were/was always higher....
I think it is *was* but women is plural so it has to be *were*, or?!
Thanks

Comment: If you have further questions, please consider asking on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "was" is correct, but FumbleFingers has given you good advice about your future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Women* is plural, but *the rate* is singular, and it's *the rate* that's higher - unless you have women stacked on top of each other, of course, which might make them higher as well.

So *the rate... was always higher* would be correct.